# Microsoft Word: is anchor character or not?

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to simulate Word's displaying of non-printing characters. There is no problem with all of them but anchors and I didn't found any info related to them. Is anchor special character placed in text or is it parameter of floating object and just displayed as special character?

Thank you for answer

Comment: If I'm following the logic of your question correctly, then it's the latter in that it NEVER can print (unlike hidden text or field codes, etc.) On screen it simply informs the user with what paragraph/range an floaing graphic is associated. It does have a represenation in the underlying WordOpenXML, however.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks, that is what I was wondering about. But to refine my question. I was asking if is possible to somehow detect anchor in text written in the Word or is it bound to the floating object and not actually present in the text. Please form your answer and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor, unlike most non-printing characters, can never print. It's merely a visual aid to inform the user with which paragraph or character a graphic with text flow formatting is associated. It's not possible to detect an anchor directly in the document text using Word's API (object model). It's bound to the graphic and would require analyzing the properties of the Shape object.

It could be determined by analyzing the document's WordOpenXML, although the term "anchor" is not used. The information could be deduced from the location and settings of the nodes that define where and how the graphic appears.

Answer (score 0):

> Is anchor special character placed in text or is it parameter of floating object and just displayed as special character?

I'm going to try to answer the "is it in text" question.

If, while debugging, you try to get a textual character for an anchor from a range's text, it won't be there. There won't even be a 0-width non-visible character there, like when you move a text cursor to the right past a non-printable character, but it doesn't actually move because there's something there (this may be editor-dependent, I have Notepad++ in mind).

So no, it's not in text.

But, at the same time, it will interfere with searches. E.g. If you put the word "text" on a line, put a text box on that line to create an anchor, and then search for "^13text" (with wildcards enabled, ^13 means the end-of-paragraph mark), it won't find it.

So yes, it must be in text because it interferes with searches.

So this might be a contradiction, but let's keep going. If it's in text, where is it? If you place the text cursor on the previous line, hold shift, and move it once to the right, the text box will be highlighted.

So it must be at the start.

But, there is also evidence that contradicts this. If you have a field at the start of the line with text on it, you can move it once to the right as before, and then once to the left, and though you have part of the line highlighted, the text box won't be part of the selection.

[image]

So, I really have no idea whether it's text or not, or where it is if so, but hopefully this helps someone else.